# Theme, School and Feat damage for Conjurations and Summonings?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers, damage, theme

Okay, I'm playing a Tiefling Fire-oriented mage with the Infernal Prince theme, Hellfire Blood feat and Pyromancy school Apprentice bonus. With all of that, my fire attacks get +2 atk and +2 dmg. I also have a +2 magic sword (multiclassed as a Swordmage to use swords as implements). Because of this, I get a +4 to both attacks and damage to fire attacks.

My questions (I've looked around online, but can't get a clear answer) are: Do my Conjurations and Summonings also get the +4 attack and damage? I know that Flaming Sphere's standard attack gets them, but does the 'foes adjacent to the sphere at the start of their turn take 1d4 + INT mod fire damage.' get the +4 damage. bonus? What about Fire Warrior and Magma Beast? Do they get the +4 attack and +4 damage. whenever they attack?

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

This is basic "how do I read 4e" stuff. Things that are relevant here (and there is a lot going on in this question so I'll try to handle it all) are:

- If the power with which you conjure a conjuration has the implement keyword, then all of its attacks get the benefits of your implement. All of its powers work with your bonuses as if *you* were the one making the attack (because you are);
- If a power or effect applies to a *damage roll* you must roll die as part of the damage expression for it to apply;
- If a power or effect says "on a hit" then you must be rolling an attack roll for it to apply.

That's basically it. To look at the specific cases you're examining:

- Fire Sphere's aura damage is a damage roll, but not an attack. So you get bonuses to damage rolls, but not where it says "when you hit";
- Your Fire Warrior and Magma Beast will both benefit from all the effects you listed.